# to find the angle for cosine! vector products

Tags: java

I am looking for an answer to find an angle-alpha for cosine.

```
cos(alpha)=RT(vector).R(vector)/(modulus)RT(vector).(modulus)R(vector)
```

then I should need to find the angle alpha.

```
public double dot1(double[] vectorA, double[] vectorB){
        double[] vecPro;
        vecPro = new double[2];
        vecPro[0] = vectorA[0]*vectorB[0];
        vecPro[1] = vectorA[1]*vectorB[1];
        return 0;
    }
```

this code is just an sample I did so far! for the dot product of `RT(vector).R(vector)`.
hmm is that correct that I did, because I am new to java language.

Comment: *"is that correct that i did?"* => does it give you the expected results?

Comment: @assylias, hmm i am asking your suggestions.

Comment: And I'm asking whether you think the program works or not, and if not what input you enter, what output you get, and what output you expect. In other words, I'm asking what you have tried...

Comment: You can verify your results with wolfram alpha.

Comment: @assylias, i tried just to solve a problem! for instance an object in an environment moves/turns from one to another position, i need the exact output is alpha the angle, for that i need to calculate in the x,y,z axis, but z-axis is T(vector) already, and the current position of the object the direction is R(vector) and new/changed position of the object is RT(vector) then there is an angle too. is that clear or still u need the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't calculate dot product. [This does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

```
public double dot1(double[] vectorA, double[] vectorB){ //if they're from R^2
        double[] vecPro = new double[2];
        vecPro[0] = vectorA[0]*vectorB[0];
        vecPro[1] = vectorA[1]*vectorB[1]; 
        //you did fine up to here
        //But, you should return the result (sum of components products) @see wiki link
        //0 surely isn't the result you want for two arbitrary vectors
        return vecPro[0] + vecPro[1]; 
}
```

Comment: hmm yes i know that i should return a value not NULL! i got it now.

Comment: 0 is `NULL`, but in C++, say.

Comment: hmm yes she is right, i have worked in C++ language, now i am new to java lang.,

Comment: not true! NULL is a Makro that returns a pointer that is NULL but it is a pointer and not an integer.

Comment: @iccthedral, actually i completed the code for dot product of RT(vector).R(vector), but i didn't get any code samples for using modulus vector dot products in java. its almost same! (modulus)RT(vector).(modulus)R(vector)

Comment: i have found the quotient part, but how to code reminder part in java code, the modulus thing, but in java %modulo% is modulus operator, i find in google, but after that the quotient divided by the diviser called reminder to get the cosine(alpha)l.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to figure out what you are really asking, but the place to find implementations of the trigonometric functions like sine, cosine and tangent is the [`java.lang.Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need those if you want the angle in radians/degrees.

Comment: actually i think the answer is alpha = (alpha)rcos(RT(vector).R(vector)/(modulus)RT(vector).(modulus)R(vector))